# Firebase Storage: Invalid argument count in `getDownloadURL`: Expected 0 arguments, received 1

Tags: angular, url, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the download url of an image right after I upload it, my code looks like this:

```
    let image       : string  = 'promo_' + this.username + '_' + new Date() + '.png',
      storageRef  : any,
      parseUpload : any;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      storageRef       = firebase.storage().ref('/promos/' + image);
      parseUpload      = storageRef.putString(this.imageHolder, 'data_url');

      parseUpload.on('state_changed', (_snapshot) => {
          // We could log the progress here IF necessary
          console.log('snapshot progess ' + _snapshot);
        },
        (_err) => {
           reject(_err);
           console.log(_err.messsage);
        },
        (success) => {
           resolve(parseUpload.snapshot); 
        })
      }).then(value => {

          storageRef.getDownloadURL(url => {
          this.list = this.af.list('/promos');
          this.list.subscribe(items => {
            let metadata = {
              customMetadata: {
                'title': this.item.title,
                'caption': this.item.caption,
                'price': this.item.price,
                'date': this.item.date,
                'typeofselect': this.item.typeofselect,
                'username': this.username,
                'url': url
              }
            }
            items.push(metadata);
          })
        }).catch(e => console.log(e.message);

      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
```

The error is:

`Firebase Storage: Invalid argument count in 'getDownloadURL': Expected 0 arguments, received 1`.

Is there something wrong with how I am getting the download url? Thanks.

Comment: yah thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass a callback-function to [`getDownloadURL`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL), since it takes no arguments. It returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) containing the URL. The URL is accessible when the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) resolves, in [`.then(url => {})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

```
storageRef.getDownloadURL()
.then(url => {
    // Do something...
});
```